# Can't get the Datepicker to show on form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, validation, datepicker

I'm trying to add Datepicker to my online form as part of my student assessment. I'm very new to all this and I'm having issues . I've downloaded and linked to my jquery UI and I've typed the code as per the jquery UI website states but the calendar doesn't pop up on my form when I click in the Date field like it suggests, I've also taken examples from this site but I still can't get it to work.

```
<head>
  <link href="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

  <script>  
  function validate(){
  date = document.getElementById("datePicker").value;

  errors = "";

    if (date == ""){
      errors += "Please supply a valid DOB \n";
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>   
  <form name= "myform" method="post" action="" class="booking">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <label for="datePicker" class="fixedwidth">Date</label>
      <input type="text" name="datePicker" id="datePicker"/>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your code in ready or load function , or insert it to a function and call it in your main js file.

Comment: Thanks very much I got my code working now, you all gave the same expert advice!

I have much to learn : )

Answer (score 2):

You have to have some jQuery code to initialize the datepicker, like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#datePicker').datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I prefer Devang's approach, as if someone new to Js/JQuery comes along, they won't know that this is the shortcut for the document.ready function :)

Comment: Thanks very much I got my code working now, you all gave the same expert advice!

I have much to learn : )

Answer (score 2):

Need to call datepicker on body load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datePicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much I got my code working now, you all gave the same expert advice!

I have much to learn : )

Answer (score 2):

```
 <script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datePicker").datepicker();
});

  function validate(){
  date = document.getElementById("datePicker").value;

  errors = "";

    if (date == ""){
      errors += "Please supply a valid DOB \n";
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much I got my code working now, you all gave the same expert advice!

I have much to learn : )

Answer (score 1):

```
You are missing this code in your script
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks very much I got my code working now, you all gave the same expert advice!    I have much to learn : )

Answer (score 1):

First initialize the datepicker UI method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datePicker").datepicker();
});
```

Since you are using jQuery, you get the value like

```
$("#datePicker").val();
```

**Update:**
To get the value after selecting it from **`datepicker`**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datePicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            alert(date);
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wLMKt/1/)

Comment: Thanks very much I got my code working now, you all gave the same expert advice!

I have much to learn : )

Comment: @Steve I would like to present a fiddle using **onSelect** http://jsfiddle.net/wLMKt/